# Backspace key in Silverlight text box shows previous page in Safari instead of editing text

Tags: silverlight, safari

I have a web page with some embedded Silverlight.  In that Silverlight I have a text box.  If I'm using Safari and I hit the backspace key while editing that Silverlight text box, Safari goes back a page as if I had clicked the "show the previous page" button.

What is going on?  It works find in IE, FF and Chrome.  Is there a way that I can fix it?  I don't want to just fix it in my browser.  I'm interested in a fix that'll fix it for all Safari users using our web app.

BTW, I'm using Safari 5.0.3 (7533.19.4)

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: BTW, this seems to only be a problem with Safari v3+ for Windows.  Works fine on my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Safari for Windows I'm afraid.  It also affects Flash, Microsoft have gone as far as saying Safari on Windows is not compatible with Silverlight (http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Safari For Windows 7, It also affects Go! Animate, XtraNormal, ICQ and every kind of Flex websites... So Microsoft have gone as far as saying Safari on Windows is not compatible with Silverlight SDK.. See the URL @ Lee Kowalkowski...